# Scott Kelly age vs Twin's

Tags: orbit, astronauts, space-station, time

Scott Kelly just returned from nearly a year of orbiting the Earth in the space station. How much younger is he than his twin, now that he has spent a significant amount of time, traveling at high speeds?

Comment: Nice question, thanks. +1 for "a significant amount of time traveling" ;)

Comment: Do you know  the exact time difference between him and his twin on the scale where we could add / remove the time dilation? Cause I would assume that the difference in time is like maybe 1 or 2 seconds. this probably won't change anything on the fact the first born twin keeps staying older :P

Comment: Also wasn't his twin brother in space aswell?

Comment: Not much younger, but temporarily two inches taller.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Neil DeGrasse Tyson [says that Scott Kelly is now 1/100 second younger](https://twitter.com/neiltyson/status/705064381420343296) than he would have been otherwise, which almost certainly isn't enough to alter the birth order of the two; I don't know which of the two was born first.

Comment: Yes, i'd say bearing a second child 1/100th of a second after the first almost certainly can't be done without significant risk to the baby.

Comment: You say things like that and some people are just going to take it as a challenge.

Comment: I think more likely a larger risk to the mother. because that would mean that the two would have to leave at the same instant... Yikes!

Comment: Scott is most likely considerably older physiologically than is his brother. A year in space takes a significant toll. Understanding that is a big part of the reason for this twin study.

Comment: The specific things that happen in long-term space habitation probably aren't identical with the specific things that happen with aging, though, so I'm reluctant to characterize that as "older physiologically".

Comment: @kimholder Assuming an average length of 20 inches, the first baby would have to be delivered at around 183 kilometers per hour (or 114 miles per hour) to be only 1/100th of a second older.

Comment: That's assuming a spherical baby of uniform density, right?

Comment: @NathanK: you made me literaly LOL... followed by a little yiks to Russell's comment.... anyway, I wanted to add: Do we know tehy are a  abdominal delivery? This could change meassures.

Comment: If you use sqrt(1-(7.7/300,000)^2) it's about .01 second difference. But the equator is moving about .5 km/s and there's also time dilation caused by gravity. I get about .008 Seconds. I guess .01 seconds is close enough.